# Parsing latin plant names with piglet fluent configuration

Tags: vb.net, piglet

I have the following tests.And Classes. Now I just need to find how to write the rules and it seemed so simple ;-). But I'm going nowhere fast. As the tags say, I would like to use and learn piglet for this.

```
Public Class Plant
    Public Property Genus As String
    Public Property Species As String
    Public Property SubSpecies As String
    Public Property IsHybrid As Boolean
End Class

Public Class ParserTests
    <Test>
    Public Sub IfGenusCanBeFoundWhenOnlyGenusAndSpiecesAreThere()
        Dim parser = New ParseLatinPlantName
        Dim result = parser.Parse("Salvia sylvatica")
        Assert.AreEqual("Salvia", result.Genus)
    End Sub

    <Test>
    Public Sub IfSpeciesCanBeFoundWhenOnlyGenusAndSpiecesAreThere()
        Dim parser = New ParseLatinPlantName
        Dim result = parser.Parse("Salvia sylvatica")
        Assert.AreEqual("sylvatica", result.Species)
    End Sub

    <Test>
    Public Sub IfSubSpeciesCanBeFoundWhenSubSpeciesIsProvided()
        Dim parser = New ParseLatinPlantName
        Dim result = parser.Parse("Salvia sylvatica sp. crimsonii")
        Assert.AreEqual("crimsonii", result.SubSpecies)
    End Sub

    <Test>
    Public Sub IfIsHybridIsTrueWhenxIsInNameCanBeFoundWhenSubSpeciesIsProvided()
        Dim parser = New ParseLatinPlantName
        Dim result = parser.Parse("Salvia x jamensis")
        Assert.IsTrue(result.IsHybrid)
    End Sub

End Class
```

And here is what I tried so far.

```
Public Class ParseLatinPlantName

        Public Function Parse(ByVal name As String) As Plant
            Dim config = ParserFactory.Fluent()
            Dim expr = config.Rule()
            Dim name1 = config.Expression()
            name1.ThatMatches("[a-z]+").AndReturns(Function(f) f)

            Dim space1 = config.Expression()
            space1.ThatMatches(" ").AndReturns(Function(f) f)

            expr.IsMadeUp.By(name).As("Genus").Followed.By(name).As("Species").WhenFound(Function(f) New Plant With {.Genus = f.Genus})

            Dim parser = config.CreateParser()
            Dim result = DirectCast(parser.Parse(name), Plant)
            Return result
        End Function
    End Class
```

Update

I got the first two tests passing thanks to Randompunter.

```
Public Class ParseLatinPlantName

        Public Function Parse(ByVal name As String) As Plant
            Dim config = ParserFactory.Fluent()
            Dim expr = config.Rule()
            Dim name1 = config.Expression()
            name1.ThatMatches("\w+").AndReturns(Function(f) f)

            expr.IsMadeUp.By(name1).As("Genus") _
                    .Followed.By(name1).As("Species") _
                    .WhenFound(Function(f) New Plant With {.Genus = f.Genus, .Species = f.Species})

            Dim parser = config.CreateParser()
            Dim result = DirectCast(parser.Parse(name), Plant)
            Return result
        End Function
    End Class
```

Comment: well, what *are* the rules? without them it's rather hard to start, crystal ball's a little hazy today... and also, what have you tried?

Comment: The rules are to get the tests passing.

Comment: What is your question?  You haven't asked anything.

Comment: The question is, how to write the rules in piglet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, your original (then corrected expression matched only lowercase letters). This was corrected by changing it to `\w+` which matched any other letter.

You second two tests failed because your grammar does not allow for more than two following letters. You will need to add a rule to make this work.

For instance, you have an example where a subspecies is provided. Assume that this takes the form where .sp xxx is an optional thing to pass, a separate rule needs to provided for this.

This passes the test for an optional subspecies

```
Public Class ParseLatinPlantName

    Public Function Parse(ByVal name As String) As Plant
        Dim config = ParserFactory.Fluent()
        Dim expr = config.Rule()
        Dim subSpecies = config.Rule()
        Dim sp = config.Expression()
        sp.ThatMatches("sp\.").AndReturns(Function(f) f)
        Dim name1 = config.Expression()
        name1.ThatMatches("\w+").AndReturns(Function(f) f)
        Dim nothing1 = config.Rule()


        expr.IsMadeUp.By(name1).As("Genus") _
                .Followed.By(name1).As("Species") _
                .Followed.By(subSpecies).As("Subspecies") _
                .WhenFound(Function(f) New Plant With {.Genus = f.Genus, .Species = f.Species, .SubSpecies = f.Subspecies})
        subSpecies.IsMadeUp.By(sp).Followed.By(name1).As("Subspecies").WhenFound(Function(f) f.Subspecies) _
            .Or.By(nothing1)

        Dim parser = config.CreateParser()
        Dim result = DirectCast(parser.Parse(name), Plant)
        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

Excuse my probably extremely shoddy VB, it was ages ago. Note that there is an expression that explicitly matches "sp." to distinguish it from any other type of name. This rule is then also matched by another rule that matches nothing. This enables the subspecies part to be optional.

I'm not to sure what you want parsed from the hybrid rule. I assume it must be something with name followed by an x and followed by some other name then it is a hybrid. To match this, add another rule to your parser.

The following parser passes all of your tests:

```
Public Class ParseLatinPlantName

    Public Function Parse(ByVal name As String) As Plant
        Dim config = ParserFactory.Fluent()
        Dim expr = config.Rule()
        Dim subSpecies = config.Rule()
        Dim hybridIndicator = config.Expression
        hybridIndicator.ThatMatches("x").AndReturns(Function(f) f)

        Dim sp = config.Expression()
        sp.ThatMatches("sp\.").AndReturns(Function(f) f)
        Dim name1 = config.Expression()
        name1.ThatMatches("\w+").AndReturns(Function(f) f)
        Dim nothing1 = config.Rule()


        expr.IsMadeUp.By(name1).As("Genus") _
                .Followed.By(name1).As("Species") _
                .Followed.By(subSpecies).As("Subspecies") _
                .WhenFound(Function(f) New Plant With {.Genus = f.Genus, .Species = f.Species, .SubSpecies = f.Subspecies}) _
                .Or.By(name1).As("FirstSpecies").Followed.By(hybridIndicator).Followed.By(name1).As("SecondSpecies") _
                .WhenFound(Function(f) New Plant With {.IsHybrid = True})

        subSpecies.IsMadeUp.By(sp).Followed.By(name1).As("Subspecies").WhenFound(Function(f) f.Subspecies) _
            .Or.By(nothing1)

        Dim parser = config.CreateParser()
        Dim result = DirectCast(parser.Parse(name), Plant)
        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

It is important that your expressions if they overlap are declared in the order of precedence. If you were to declare `name1` before `hybridIndicator` the `x` would be recognized as a name, causing the parsing to fail. And as you probably noticed, Piglet ignores whitespace by default, there is no need to make a rule for it. If this setting is not desired, there is an option to turn it off in the configurator. (use the Ignore method)